# Trying to understand the phrasing of an elementary combinatorics question's answer

Tags: combinatorics

This is from Feller's book on probability. I like the book, but sometimes the phrasing of things is not entirely clear to me.

One worked example is the calculation of the probability of getting all thirteen face values in a hand of bridge. I quote the book:

> For each face value we have the free choice of a suit. The hand may be considered as a sample with repetitions of size 13 of the population of four suits.

I just want to make sure I understand the second sentence. Is he calculating the possible hands that contain a combination of 13 face cards in the following manner?

The population is four suits $S = {H,D,C,S}$. Let a hand be a 13 sized combination of these four suits, i.e., a 13 sized sample of the population done with replacement. The face value of the card is not explicitly stated, but one interpretation could be that the index of the card is the face value. For example, the sample ${HDH...}$ would be the 2 of hearts, the 3 of diamonds, the 4 of hearts, etc.

Is this right?

I know this is kind of a soft question, but I really want to make sure I understand the intuition of how to calculate these combinations.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the intended interpretation.  The "face value" here is the "number (or letter)" that appears on the card.  This term is more often called the *rank* of the card.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck).  As the text suggests, for the ace, you have four choices available ($\heartsuit,\spadesuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit$), and for the two you again have four choices available,... As there will be exactly one card of each rank, and you have four choices as to the suit of each card, there are $4^{13}$ possible hands in question.

Comment: 4^13 / binomial(52,13) is roughly one in 10,000.